# Custom controller enable Gzip compression?

Tags: magento-1.9, gzip

We have a custom controller returning some json, this doesn't appear to be gzipped.

The response has: `Content-Type: application/json`, I've modified the root `.htaccess` to enable gzip but it doesn't seem to make any difference **for the controller**.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                "application/javascript" \
                                "application/json" \
                                "application/ld+json" \
                                "application/manifest+json" \
                                "application/rdf+xml" \
                                "application/rss+xml" \
                                "application/schema+json" \
                                "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                "application/x-javascript" \
                                "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                "application/xml" \
                                "font/eot" \
                                "font/opentype" \
                                "image/bmp" \
                                "image/svg+xml" \
                                "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                "image/x-icon" \
                                "text/cache-manifest" \
                                "text/css" \
                                "text/html" \
                                "text/javascript" \
                                "text/plain" \
                                "text/vcard" \
                                "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                "text/vtt" \
                                "text/x-component" \
                                "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                "text/xml"
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>
```

It does make css/js gzipped so the mod_deflate seems to be enabled and working.

**I would prefer to not need to modify the controller itself** because on our dev/live site we have varnish + cdn and those already take care of gzipping it.

The controller is made in a pretty "core way" so I don't get why it's not working. Anyone have any ideas?

The first class is the controller that is been called from an ajax request in frontend using GET.

```
class Vendor_Elasticsearch_CatalogController extends Vendor_React_Controller_AbstractController {
    // ...
    protected function _sendResponse($response, $httpCode)
    {
        if (is_array($response)) {               
            $response = $result = json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        }
        $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
            ->setHeader('HTTP/1.0', $httpCode, true);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
    }        
}

abstract class Vendor_React_Controller_AbstractController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple.. just enable gzip in my local php.ini

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```